# Add Badge on a hamburger menu icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi Please help I am trying to add a red Badge on a hamburger menu icon in the flutter app like below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with `badges` plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file under dependencies:

```
badges: ^2.0.2
```

then import,

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
```

finally add `Badge` in `AppBar`,

```
AppBar(
    leading: Badge(
       position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 10, end: 10),
        badgeContent: null,
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
        ),
    ),
    title: Text('Badge Demo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```

Comment: Latest version is:  ^2.0.2

Comment: Solution looks good. For the menu to work again, I had to implement "Scaffold(key: scaffoldKey" and then onPressed I used:  onPressed: () { scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer(); }

Answer (score 0):

Using `Stack`, similar sample code:

```dart
class NotificationIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool active;
  final double marginTopLeft;

  const NotificationIcon({Key key, this.active = true, this.marginTopLeft})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final color = active ? Colors.white : const Color(0xff40a9ff);
    final margin = marginTopLeft ?? 17;

    return Container(
      width: 24,
      height: 24,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: margin,
            top: margin,
            child: Container(
              width: 8,
              height: 8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: color,
                  ),
                  width: 5,
                  height: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using the `Stack` widget. I have given an example of how you can use stack to achieve that. Note that you have to use `Scaffold.of(yourContext).openDrawer()` to open the attached drawer (as I've done here) since the hamburger icon is manually placed there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Example());
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Example",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            onTap: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                width: 40,
                height: 25,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                      color: Colors.grey[850],
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 25,
                      top: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            width: 10,
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text("Hello"),
          actions: [
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text("Welcome")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text(
          "Some Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        leading: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          onTap: () {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              width: 40,
              height: 25,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 25,
                    top: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 10,
                      height: 10,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please use this. And if you want to show the number as well, you can use Badge too.